# How can I unit-test Exception thrown inside a Lambda?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, option-type

I have a method:

```
public UserEntity authentication(final UserEntity auth)
    throws AuthenticationException, EmailNotFoundException {
    final AtomicReference<UserEntity> atomic = new AtomicReference<>();
    this.repository
        .findByEmail(auth.getEmail())
        .ifPresentOrElse(
            usr -> {
                if (Objects.equals(usr.getPassword(), auth.getPassword())) {
                    atomic.set(usr);
                } else {
                    throw new AuthenticationException();
                }
            },
            () -> {
                throw new EmailNotFoundException(auth.getEmail());
            }
        );
    return atomic.get();
}
```

This is how the user authorization test looks like:

```
@Test
void userAuthentication_success() {
    given(this.repository.findByEmail(this.user.getEmail()))
        .willReturn(Optional.of(this.user));
    assertThat(this.underTest.authentication(this.user))
        .isInstanceOf(UserEntity.class)
        .isEqualTo(this.user);
    verify(this.repository)
        .findByEmail(this.user.getEmail());
}
```

Is there any way to check the case when a user has entered the wrong password?

In the case when I send the wrong password, it doesn't work because
`given(this.repository.findByEmail(this.user.getEmail())).willReturn(Optional.of(this.user));` makes `repository.findByEmail()` return the result before you get to checking the password.

Comment: Have you tried `assertThrows`?

Comment: @RobSpoor it doesn't throws anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need this formidable multiline lambda. Having `if`-statement outside a lambda expression is way cleaner than having then cramming it inside the lambda.

And there's no need to utilize convoluted logic with `AtomicReference` unless you have an intention to perplex the reader of the code.

There are three cases: user doesn't exist, user-credentials are wrong, user's data is valid. Let's deal with them separately:

```
public UserEntity authentication(final UserEntity auth)
    throws AuthenticationException, EmailNotFoundException {

    UserEntity user = this.repository
        .findByEmail(auth.getEmail())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EmailNotFoundException(auth.getEmail()));
    
    if (Objects.equals(user.getPassword(), auth.getPassword())) {
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }
    
    return user;
}
```

To test if the exceptions are being thrown as expected, you can use one of the flavor of `assertThrows()`.

Here is an example of test checking whether `AuthenticationException` would be thrown when user credentials are incorrect:

```
@Test
void userAuthenticationFailure() {
    assertThrows(AuthenticationException.class,
                 () -> this.underTest.authentication(UserWithWorngPassword),
                 "Wrong user password should trigger an Exception");
}
```

Comment: +1 this version is a little cleaner than mine because Optional doesn't have peek, which would be neater than a map here

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would refactor your code to avoid side-effects:

```
public UserEntity authentication(final UserEntity auth)
    throws AuthenticationException, EmailNotFoundException {
    return this.repository
        .findByEmail(auth.getEmail())
        .map(usr -> {
           if (!Objects.equals(usr.getPassword(), auth.getPassword())) {
               throw new AuthenticationException();
           }
           return usr;
        }).orElseThrow(() -> { throw new EmailNotFoundException(auth.getEmail()); });
}
```

Then, I don't see an issue with mocking `this.repository.findByEmail`, I just think you made it return a valid user with the correct password. Something like:

```java
given(this.repository.findByEmail(this.user.getEmail())).willReturn(Optional.of(this.user.withPassword("wrong password")));
```